Change Named Range formula column (or row) reference depending on selected cell in Excel
I've downloaded this Gantt chart project planner from Microsoft. I'm trying to figure out how it works.
Interestingly, after looking at the Name Manager in the Formulas tab, there are some named ranges that use a formula that automatically changes its column (but not its row) reference depending on which cell is currently selected (active) when I open the Name Manager. These named ranges are PercentCompleteBeyond, PeriodInActual, and PeriodInPlan. And specifically, row 4 is kept constant.
For example, when you download the file and open it for the first time, cell A1 will be selected by default. If you open the Name Manager, the formulas for the previous named ranges will contain A$4:

Or if I instead click on cell V8 and then open the Name Manager, now the previous named ranges will contain V$4:

I'd like to know how this is achieved, since I'm recreating this project planner in another workbook.

Nevermind, you need to literally just ignore the dollar sign ($) when defining the reference in the formula of the Named Range.
